# mac terminal giving notifications every time I exit the tab for unknown reason

Tags: terminal, mouse, macos-ventura

On Ventura 13.4
Basically, sometimes I forget to click off of the terminal and accidentally scroll with my mouse which goes through the command history. This causes the notification bell to go off quite a few times, and then when I leave the terminal tab I get the notification bell again, as well as the red dot in the dock. I currently have nothing going on in that tab, and it still keeps going off.

The only way I know how to stop it is by closing the tab. I'm often logged into another system though, so this can be pretty annoying if I have to log back in. I have no idea what it is even notifying me of. I've tried running different commands, clearing the screen, and looking through some of the settings but nothing has stopped the behavior. I was hoping there would be a setting related to mouse scroll buttons thinking that could prevent this behavior, but I haven't seen any. So, I would like to figure out how to end the notifications without having to close the tab.